# how to use object.value in value attribute of option tag in angular2 using semantic UI

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

The below code snippet is a semantic UI select block. I'm using `*ngFor` to fetch a list of objects from a list variable. I'm unable to select multiple values because the `value` attribute is treating the value of `{{x}}` as a string. How can I resolve this issue?

```html
<div class="ui multiple selection dropdown">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Choose</div>
  <select multiple="" id="multi-select">
     <option value="">Functions</option>
     <option *ngFor="let x of functionList" value="{{x}}">
        {{x.functionName}}
     </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

`functionList` is a array of json, which looks like this:

```html
functionList = [{
   functionName : string,
   functionValue : string
}]
```

Comment: Can you post in the question what is `functionList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the double brackets for the value, just use double quotes.

Try this:

```html
<div class="ui multiple selection dropdown">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Choose</div>
  <select multiple="" id="multi-select">
    <option value="">Functions</option>
    <option *ngFor="let x of functionList" [value]="x.value">{{x.functionName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

For the `[value]` some kind of value should be used. If `x` is Object it won't work.

Comment: `x` should be value and from the example `x.functionName` I think it's Object